# Session error after uploading wordpress site on live

Tags: php, wordpress, session

Following errors come after uploading site to live:

> **Warning**: session_start() [function.session-start]:
>   open(D:\TEMP\PHP\sess_h7pba1el9krq2dpt2klsm0v6c1, O_RDWR) failed: No
>   such file or directory (2)
>
> **Warning**: Unknown: open(D:\TEMP\PHP\sess_h7pba1el9krq2dpt2klsm0v6c1,
>   O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0
>
> **Warning**: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify
>   that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (D:\TEMP\PHP)
>   in Unknown on line 0

On the local system the site is working fine. The above errors come only after it is uploaded.

how do I get them resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP can't save it's session files. In spite of you're using wp the problem isn't related with it, it's a server problem.

Depending on the type of server you should:

- Ask hosts support to fix it OR
- Edit the `session.save_path` var in your php.ini

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is a function ini_set in php which can be used to change php configuration without modifying php.ini file. I created temp folder in my directory. I want to set session.save_path. Do you know where to put it? I tried putting in wp-settings but it doesnt affect the configuration settings

Comment: You should put it in wp-config, that file isn't changed during wordpress updates. However even existing the `ini_set` function some servers just ignore it, in that cases you do have to alter php.ini or ask server support to do that for you :(